# woocommerce not going into the checkout response function

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a plugin for woocommerce. It's a custom payment gateway.

**Problem**:
When returning back from my website to woocommerce, I pass the result as completed or failed in the return URL (eg: http://woocommercetestwebsite.com/checkout/order-received/771/?key=wc_order_5955555324&message=completed).

How do I parse the above mentioned URL on the Order Received page, so that I can mark the order as complete or failed in woocommerce?

I tried adding: `add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . strtolower( get_class( $this ) ), array( $this, 'check_ipn_response' ));` in my plugin. But it doesn't work. Is this a wrong way?

```
public function check_ipn_response(){
    try{
        global $woocommerce;

        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $order_status = $_GET['message'];

        if ($order_status == 'completed') {
            $order->payment_complete();
            $order->update_status('completed');
        } else if ($order_status == 'failed') {
            $order->update_status('failed');
        }

        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your URL example uses 'Success' but your code is checking for 'Completed'

Comment: I have edited the question again. thanks for pointing it out. @Parker